# IIS7 Compression Failure

Tags: http, iis-7, http-compression

I'm having issues with IIS7's static compression. I've read some of the other posts, and I'm out of options. Here's what I have:

In the applicationHost.config, I've set up:

```
    <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files" staticCompressionDisableCpuUsage="100">
        <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" staticCompressionLevel="9" />
        <staticTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="true" />
        </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
```

The "enable static compression" checkbox is enabled for my site.

I get a big fat uncompressed file when I load up the site. If I look at the request headers, I see:

Accept-Encoding : gzip,deflate

but, in the response, I get:

> Content-Type: application/x-javascript
>
> Last-Modified: Fri, 10 Jul 2009 01:13:41 GMT
>
> Accept-Ranges: bytes
>
> Etag: "3be6da9fb0ca1:0"
>
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
>
> X-Powered-By: UrlRewriter.NET 2.0.0, ASP.NET
>
> Date: Fri, 10 Jul 2009 03:39:35 GMT
>
> Content-Length: 81515

Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Also, FWIW, I'm running in Integrated, not "Classic" mode.

UPDATE: I got it working, but I'm not sure why it works now. All I did was enable dynamic compression for the site, and everything started working. Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem and I believe it is because we are using UrlRewriter.NET. While it is enabled all file requests are routed through the handler to determine whether they should be url rewritten or not. This changes a css or js file into a dynamic request instead of static, therefore GZip compression seems to not work in IIS7 until you check the dynamic content compression box. That's my theory anyway...

Comment: Great theory - I think you're correct, as we were using the exact same lib.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, but I'm not sure why it works now. All I did was enable dynamic compression for the site, and everything started working. If someone can give me an explanation for *why* this worked, I'll give them credit on the answer.

Comment: Are you sure your page was static?  Sounds like it was a dynamic page, to me.

Comment: It was a plain js script...doesn't get much more static than that :)

Answer (score -2):

I'm not that good in IIS7 compression but I want to advise you to have a look at [Helicon Ape mod-gzip](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/doc/mod_gzip.htm) module that provides comprehensive compression capabilities. The guide on how to enable and use Helicon Ape mod-gzip is [here](http://helicontech.blogspot.com/2009/03/guide-how-to-enable-modgzip-compression.html).

Comment: Isn't it weird how all your answers recommend Helicon products. I wonder why.

Comment: Why can't I advise a tool I enjoy to people who may also benefit from using it? I'm not advertising it but just sharing my experience.

Comment: Uh-huh. And yet every answer you've given on Stack Overflow has recommended a Helicon tool. Your marketing attempts are very transparent.

Comment: If you check my answers once again you'll see that not all of them refer to Helicon products. I did advise it a couple of times, but don't you think it was relevant in that cases. I'm not trying to put Helicon link anywhere possible, 'cause that's not my goal (I'm not at all a marketer).